# Взаимодействия с папками на Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

Каким образом на Python 2.7 я могу открывать папку с файлами, а потом выйти с папки. А потом зайти в другую папку(следующую по порядку)?

Comment: os.chdir? . . .

Comment: А как с помощью os.chdir можно взаимодействовать с папками по-порядку?
То есть, я хочу сначала зайти в папку:
E:\\folder1 и выйти из нее.
Потом зайти в следующую папку E:\\twst и выйти из нее. (Названия папок отличаються одна от второй и общего не имеют)
Но мне надо что бы все выполнялось по порядку.
Можно примеры скинуть?

Comment: `os.chdir('E:\\folder1')` потом `os.chdir('E:\\twst')` и так далее по порядку